# Reputation should show value before +/-

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

I think under the reputation tab and right next to the reputation +/- numbers there should be a value representing my reputation before addition or substration of reputation  [image]

In the above image that position is the one marked as red.

Lets say i my reputation is 912 so it should be like

910 +2  .............

895 +15 .............

910 -15 .............

900 +10 .............

Comment: What's the advantage of this feature?

Comment: I suppose it might help one assess where the user was in comparison to their [so] history.

Comment: I've found myself wanting this feature as well but only out of curiosity.  I do not believe that this would provide any *useful* information and might clutter up the reputation view more than it already is...

Comment: No, it's just one big clutter. If you want so badly to know your past reputation do the math yourself. Can't see any reason to force this on everyone.

Comment: @Lix: vote to delete this question.

Comment: You can see your daily reputation history on your network profile.  Do you really need finer granularity than that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We really can't justify this, as it's quite expensive for Skeet for example.  To get the data needed, you have to walk the entire rep history table to get it (either in SQL or in code, same thing).  We'd have to do this for every request or cache it (twice, inaccurately, and I won't go dive into the dozen cases this doesn't work) across requests.

And yes, I *know* exactly how expensive it is because I actually do this for a developer screen (of which there are many) we built as part of debugging and making sure all rep change cases are now accounted for as part of the near-real-time-rep setup.

Comment: So you are saying that **you** have it, but don't want to share ;)  Didn't think of the uber-high-rep-users case...  Would a tooltip of sorts with the calculation for that specific rep change be a viable alternative perhaps?

Comment: @Lix - it's not a simple calculation, you have to pull back the full history for that user from the beginning of time and start it up...tooltip or not, that's where the cost lies.  Either SQL pain, or data pain from SQL then handled on the web tier.  While neither of those is *that* expensive, it adds up fast when multiplied millions of times :)